# How to adjust Eclipse console's clock (time)

Tags: eclipse, console

In eclipse, in the console window, there is a bar which shows the date and time.
In my eclipse the date and time aren't set correctly to the current time. I've tried to find how to adjust it but without succeed.

Any ideas?

Comment: The only date / time I see in the console view is the time of the last program launch or termination.

Comment: this is what i mean, when i launch a program there is a mismatch between the time is shown for the real time i started it. looks like it doesn't synchronize to the current time. @greg-449